# Running Ray on top of AWS Batch multi-node?

Tags: python, distributed-computing, ray, aws-batch, ray-train

I am interested in running Ray on AWS Batch multi-node. This is a pattern that hasn't been done before on Ray, and thus, there's no documentation on it. But, I'd really like to try it since Ray can be installed on-premise as well.

I stood up the AWS Batch multi-node gang-scheduled closer and ran the following commands:

1. For the head node:

```
subprocess.Popen(f"ray start --head --node-ip-address {current.parallel.main_ip} --port {master_port} --block", shell=True).wait()
```

2. For the worker nodes:

```
import ray
node_ip_address = ray._private.services.get_node_ip_address()
subprocess.Popen(f"ray start --node-ip-address {node_ip_address} --address {current.parallel.main_ip}:{master_port} --block", shell=True).wait()
```

The head node seems to be working, but there's some issue with the worker nodes not syncing with the head node.

I get the following output in `stderr`:

```
[2023-07-28 09:25:55,500 I 427 427] global_state_accessor.cc:356: This node has an IP address of 10.14.52.21, but we cannot find a local Raylet with the same address. This can happen when you connect to the Ray cluster with a different IP address or when connecting to a container.
```

Any insight on how I can get Ray working on AWS Batch multi-node would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are the nodes in the same AWS network? Have you tried Ray Client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to be an issue with `pydantic`. I downgraded `pydantic` version to `1.10.12` and after that, it seemed to work like a charm.

Also, for AWS Batch, the worker nodes need to be kept alive. So there needs to be a heartbeat where the worker nodes ping the head node to check if the job is complete, and if not, then you execute `time.sleep`

Answer (score -1):

AWS Batch MNP child jobs get an environment variable of the head node's private IP address `AWS_BATCH_JOB_MAIN_NODE_PRIVATE_IPV4_ADDRESS`

Are you using this value to connect to the head node? Sorry not familiar with Ray and where it is grabbing those IP addresses from.